# WMIC output to text file

Tags: output, wmic

I have a script that I run on all pc's that I image and it basically looks and tells me if a program is installed and if so, what version.
When I run my command in a CMD window it works.
But as part of my script, it deletes everything in the txt file and adds weird characters.
Here is the Edge code.

```
:Edge
If  exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"  (
 echo Edge is installed >> C:\Temp\Message.txt
 SET "EDGE=Y"
 wmic /OUTPUT:"C:\Temp\Message.txt" datafile where 'name="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"' get version 
) Else (
SET "EDGE=N"&echo Edge is Not installed >> C:\Temp\Message.txt
)
```

Here is the result
Version
94.0.992.50
?????????????4???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

I am at a loss.....

Comment: Refer to [How to detect installed Edge version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/244265/how-to-detect-installed-edge-version-to-automate-d.html)
if you want to find the Edge version by checking the registry keys then you can try to check at the below location.

Registry path: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon`, `Key name: version`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try with this batch script that use a powershell command in one line :

```
(Get-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable").Version
```

Tested only on Windows 10 (32 bits)

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Edge Version with Powershell and Batch
Set PassPSCMD="(Get-AppxPackage -Name "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable").Version"
Set "LogFile=C:\Temp\Message.txt"
Call :RunPS %PassPSCMD% EdgeVersion
>"%LogFile%" (
    If defined EdgeVersion (
        echo Edge has a version : %EdgeVersion%
    ) else (
        echo Edge is not Installed !
    )
)
If Exist "%LogFile%" Start "" /MAX "%LogFile%"
Exit
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: A function that would execute powershell script and return a value from it.
:: <RetValue> the returned value to be set like in this case we need Edge Version
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
@for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`Powershell -C %1`) do set "%2=%%i"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Or with `Reg Query` in Pure Batch is faster than the previous script

Tested only on Windows 10 (32 bits)

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Edge Version with Reg Query in Pure Batch
Set "LogFile=C:\Temp\Message.txt"
Set "MyKey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Edge\BLBeacon"

@for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (
    'Reg Query "%MyKey%" 2^>nul ^| find /I "Version"'
) do (Set "EdgeVersion=%%a")

>"%LogFile%" (
    If defined EdgeVersion (
        echo Edge has a version : %EdgeVersion%
    ) else (
        echo Edge is not Installed !
    )
)
If Exist "%LogFile%" Start "" /MAX "%LogFile%" & Exit
```

---

And if you insist to use `WMIC` give a shot for this batch script :

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Edge Version with WMIC
Set "LogFile=C:\Temp\Message.txt"
SET "ARCH=x64" 
IF /I "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (IF NOT DEFINED PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 SET "ARCH=x86")
If /I "%ARCH%"=="x86" ( set "PrgFiles=%ProgramFiles%" ) else ( set "PrgFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%" )
Set EdgePath=%PrgFiles%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
echo( & echo Getting Version of "%EdgePath%"
Call :GetVersion "%EdgePath%" Version
echo EDGE Version : %Version%
echo EDGE Version : %Version%>>"%LogFile%"
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak>nul
If Exist "%LogFile%" Start "" /MAX "%LogFile%" & Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetVersion <App> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
Set "App=%~1"
Set "App=%App:\=\\%"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
    'wmic datafile where "name='%App%'" get version /Value 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```